# Umount + hdparm setting for an external hd

Tags: linux, automounting, usb-device, external-hdd, hdparm

How can I obtain that in umount state but connected to usb port my external hd don't work to preserve it? It's possible to re-mount it any time? I would like to keep it on for just an hour a day to do some writing and then keep it off for the rest of the tim. Hdparm can help? I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You'd probably better use *udisksctl* with the *power-off* option set when you are done.

Comment: I've chacked the help and found "Note that as some physical devices contain multiple drives (for example 4-in-1 flash
           card reader USB devices) powering off one drive may affect other drives. As such there
           are not a lot of guarantees associated with performing this action. Usually the effect
           is that the drive disappears as if it was unplugged." It's safe for a zimaboard832 or a micro server? How can I "Power-On" it without re-attach it manually?

Comment: I need this on my Proxmox VE 8 zimaboard832 that is based on Debian Bookworm.
Anyone have ever use this software and can tell me if it work fine and how can I script this automation?

[uhubctl][1]


  [1]: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/uhubctl

Comment: Sorry pal ! I just don't know that sort of system and therefore just cannot tell for sure. And you are correct regarding what you quoted. So I'm afraid you'll have to test by yourself. Have luck ! (Not to say that your comment (regarding the precise device should imho be copied into your question)

Comment: Thank's a lot I'm learning how to use this platform and I'm not english so maybe I've made mistakes, thanks a lot for replies.